# Custom Build Task for VSTS - package multiple tasks in one VSIX?

Tags: azure-pipelines, visual-studio-extensions, azure-pipelines-build-task, vsixmanifest

Is it possible to "bundle" multiple custom VSTS build tasks in one VSIX file.

I can see how it would be best practice (single responsibility and all) to create one extension per task, but **is it possible**?

If so, an example manifest, and a link to someone who has done this would be very appreciated.

My intended file structure is.  It will be very easy to switch to one vsix per task if I have to.

```
Custom-Tasks
  - Task1
    - task.json
    - task.ps1
  - Task2
    - task.json
    - task.ps1
  - Task3
    - Task3V1
      - task.json
      - task.ps1
    - Task3V2
      - task.json
      - task.ps1
  extension-icon.png
  extension-manifest.json
  extension-tests.ps1
  build-publish.ps1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add multiple *files* and *contributions*, one for each task.

Ex:

```
"files": [
    {
        "path": "Task1"
    },
    {
        "path": "Task2"
    },
    {
        "path": "Task3"
    }
],
"contributions": [
    {
        "id": "task-1-guid",
        "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "Task1"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "task-2-guid",
        "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "Task2"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "task-3-guid",
        "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "Task3"
        }
    }
]
```

Any number of extensions on the marketplace have multiple tasks bundled in them that you can use as a reference.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  In addition to that, I had to add two "files" locations.  Do you mind if I edit your answer to reflect that change?

Answer (score -1):

Multiple tasks with multiple versions layout documented here: [Multiple versions layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/integrate-build-task?view=azure-devops#multiple-versions-layout)